# Why `FindMaximum` doesn't work in my example

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

Consider the following function

```
n = 200000`200;
k = 2 n - 50`200;
μ = 10`200^-5;
ν = 10`200^-5;
qhat = k/(2 n);

fun[s_] := 
 Log[(E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n μ) qhat^(-1 + 4 n ν))/
  NIntegrate[ E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n μ) qhat^(-1 + 4 n ν), 
             {qhat, 1/(4 n + 1), 1 - 1/(4 n + 1)},  MaxRecursion -> 12]]
```

I can `Plot` my function in order to estimate the maximum

```
Plot[fun[s], {s, 0, 0.2}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "P(qhat | s)"}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The maximum seems to be around 0.075. Let's calculate it:

```
FindMaximum[fun[s], {s, 0.075}, MaxIterations -> 100]
```

> The integrand [...] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the
>   region with boundaries

Why can't I estimate the maximum with `FindMaximum`?

Comment: are defined all the constant in the fun[s] and try NMaximize[fun[s],s]

Comment: @K_v Yes, all constant are defined. I edited my post to add exactly how I defined them. `NMaximize[fun[s],s]` doesn't work either. It returns the same error message than `FindMaximum`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a recurring issue.  Replace `fun[s_]:=` by `fun[s_?NumericQ]:=` to eliminate your error messages.  `FindMaximum` then will give the answer, `{9.09757, {s -> 0.0799914}}`, which appears to be correct, despite the fact that `FindMaximum` gives the warning message that

```
FindMaximum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient increase in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances."
```

See this [Answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) for a discussion of `?NumericQ`.

Comment: Use arbitrary precision (e.g., `WorkingPrecision -> 16`) in `FindMaximum` rather than machine precision to avoid `FindMaximum::lstol` warning.

Comment: @BobHanlon, Good point, although it does not change the answer much: `{9.097567799873060, {s -> 0.07999124376931556}}`.