# What is the range of values $x$ for which $f(x)$ is higher than $k$ over a given domain?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

What is the easiest way to answer the following question in Mathematica:

**Given a function $f(x)=y$, what is the range of values $x$ for which $y$ is higher than some number $k$ over the domain of $x$ $[a;b]$?**

---

For example consider the function:

[image]

What is the range of values of $x$, for which $f(x)$ is greater than $k=4.8$ over the domain [-2;2]?

**As I am aiming to apply this method to a complicated function, I would like numerical approximations rather than an analytical solution.**

Comment: Over a finite domain `{x, a, b}` or over all real numbers `x`?

Comment: Note `Reduce[-x^3 + 3 x^2 - 2 x + 5 > 48/10, x]` works on the sample function...but I'm not sure what kind of difficult functions you have in mind.  Would numerical approximations be satisfactory, or do you desire symbolic solutions?

Comment: Oh good points. Well, I will apply this method to a finite domain (of real numbers only). So let's say over the domain [-2;2]. And I would need numerical approximations. I edited my post. For info, my function of interest looks more or less like that `Log[(E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n \[Mu]) qhat^(-1 + 
     4 n \[Nu]))/
 NIntegrate[
  E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n \[Mu]) qhat^(-1 + 
      4 n \[Nu]), {qhat, 1/(4 n + 1), 1 - 1/(4 n + 1)}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 12]]`. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

```
f[x_] := Sin[3 x^2] + x;
```

and criterion `k = 1`, all in the range `[-2,2]`.

One can use `Solve[]`, `NSolve[]` or `FindRoot[]` to get crossing points, but it helps to search for solutions using a number of starting points.

```
myCrossings = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[(x /. FindRoot[f[x] == 1, {{x, Range[-2, 2, .4]}}])]
```

Then, include the lower and upper limit of your `x` range:

```
PrependTo[myCrossings, -2];
AppendTo[myCrossings, 2]
```

Then, depending upon whether the value of `f[x]` at the lower limit of the range is greater or less than the criterion (here, `k = 1`), choose pairs of crossing points for the corresponding ranges of `x`:

```
If[f[-2] > 1, Partition[myCrossings, 2, 2], Partition[Drop[myCrossings, 1], 2, 2]]
```

(*
{{0.443523, 1.02785}, {1.39912, 1.86883}, {1.94362, 2}}
*)

If you want a more easily readable output:

```
#[[1]] < x < #[[2]] & /@ If[f[-2] > 1, Partition[myCrossings, 2, 2], Partition[Drop[myCrossings, 1], 2, 2]]
```

(*
{0.443523 < x < 1.02785, 1.39912 < x < 1.86883, 1.94362 < x < 2}
*)

It is true, in the extremely unlikely case that you have a local maximum or local minimum of f[x] at a root--and thus f[x] remains below the criterion or remains above the criterion on both sides of the root--you might have to check for solution ranges.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way most likely depends on the nature of the function. The function referred to in a comment by the OP seems to be like one in another post that it is concave down.  The solution in such a case is quite simple and would consist at most of one interval.  However, if the interval is to be $[-2,2]$, then it is not exactly that function.  An oscillatory function is quite different, and the easy solution to a concave/convex function would probably not solve the oscillatory case.

Dealing with the more general case, then, I can think of two "easiest" solutions.  One involving `NDSolve` is likely to be quite robust.  The other uses `Plot`, may be less robust, but is likely to be faster.  For highly oscillatory functions, some tweaking of the number of `PlotPoints` might be required.  (An extremely oscillatory function is likely to require some manual adjustment in all cases, anyway.)  Both methods assume that the function is continuous over the interval.  A discontinuous function may be handled by applying the methods here to the intervals over which the function is continuous.

**`NDSolve` method**

```
higher[f_, k_, {a_, b_}] :=
 Module[{ifun, in, s, t, x1},
  Reap[
    NDSolve[{ifun[t] == f[t],
      in[a] == Boole[f[a] > k], x1[a] == a,
      s'[t] == 1, s[a] == a,
      WhenEvent[f[t] > k, {in[t] -> 1, x1[t] -> t}],
      WhenEvent[f[t] < k, If[in[t] == 1, Sow[{x1[t], t}, Interval]]; {in[t] -> 0}]},
     ifun, {t, a, b}, DiscreteVariables -> {in, x1}],
    Interval][[2, 1]]
  ]
```

[Note: [I may have found a bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72258/extraneous-reaped-data-with-ndsolve-and-whenevent) using `Reap` with `NDSolve`.  I had to use a tag with `Sow`/`Reap` here, because extra data was sown.  I chose `Interval` for the tag; anything would have done.]

**`Plot`/zero-crossings method**

I used Mr.Wizard's adaptation of David Carraher's zero-crossings function, which can be found here: [Find zero crossing in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/find-zero-crossing-in-a-list/10653#10653).

```
davidZC2[l_] := SparseArray[#]["AdjacencyLists"] & /. 
  SApos_ :> With[{c = SApos[l]}, {c[[#]], c[[# + 1]]}\[Transpose] &@
     SApos@Differences@Sign@l[[c]]]

higher2[f_, k_, {a_, b_}] :=
 (plot = Plot[f[s], {s, a, b}, PlotRange -> All];
  With[{xy = First@Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity]},
   Partition[
    Join[
     If[f[a] > k, {a}, {}],
     Block[{s},
      s /. FindRoot[
          f[s] == k,
          {s, Mean[xy[[#, 1]]], Sequence @@ xy[[#, 1]]}
          ] & /@ davidZC2[xy[[All, 2]] - k]
      ],
     If[f[b] > k, {b}, {}]
     ],
    2]])
```

(The `plot` is stored in a global variable for inspection in case the result seems questionable.)

**Examples**

From [Why `FindMaximum` doesn't work in my example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72218/why-findmaximum-doesnt-work-in-my-example):

```
n = 200000;
k = 2 n - 50;
μ = 10^-5;
ν = 10^-5;
qhat = k/(2 n);

Clear[fun];
fun[s_?NumericQ] := Log[(E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n μ) qhat^(-1 + 4 n ν))/
   NIntegrate[E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n μ) qhat^(-1 + 4 n ν),
    {qhat, 1/(4 n + 1), 1 - 1/(4 n + 1)}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 12]]

higher[fun, 0.1, {0, 2}]
(*  {{0.0109522, 0.266125}}  *)

higher2[fun, 0.1, {0, 2}]
(*  {{0.0109522, 0.266125}}  *)
```

Random example:

```
g[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[x Sin[20 t] Exp[-t^3], {t, 0, x}];
higher2[g, 0.05, {-2, 2}]
Show[plot, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0.05, .1}}, Frame -> True]
(*
  {{-1.93866, -1.78522}, {-1.6299, -1.48044}, {-1.31331, -1.18644},
   {-0.963237, -0.923499}, {0.738644, 0.853318}, {1.02542, 2}}
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to build a Piecewise function. For example, the piecewise function `g[x]` returns `1` whenever `f[x]` is in the region larger than `c` and `0` otherwise. Placed in a Manipulate, it shows the region over which f[x] is larger than the value of `c`.

```
f[x_] := Sin[3 x^2] + x;
g[x_, c_] := Piecewise[{{1, c < f[x]}, {0, True}}]
Manipulate[Plot[g[x, c], {x, -2, 2}], {c, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

The above example borrows the function `f[x]` from David Stork's answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** You can also use the options `Mesh` and `MeshShading` using the information from `FunctionDomain[f]`:

```
mesh = {Cases[fd, _?NumericQ, {0, Infinity}]};

Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
 Mesh -> mesh, MeshShading -> {Blue, Red}, MeshStyle ->Opacity[0]]
```

[image]

For the second example below, using `f2` and `mesh2 = {Cases[fd2, _?NumericQ, {0, Infinity}]};` gives

[image]

**Update 2:** You can more conveniently use the result of `FunctionDomain` in setting the color function, e.g.,   `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[fd, Red, Blue]]`, in both examples in the original answer.

**Original answer:**

[**FunctionDomain**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) (in versions 10+)

There are two new Version 10 functions, `FunctionDomain` and `NumberLinePlot,` that you might find useful.

Using the example in David's answer:

```
f[x_] := Sin[3 x^2] + x  

fd = FunctionDomain[{f[x],-2<x<2 && f[x]>1.}, x,Reals]
(*  0.443523 < x < 1.02785 || 1.39912 < x < 1.86883 || 1.94362 < x < 2. *)

NumberLinePlot[fd, {x, 0, 3}, ImageSize->500, ImagePadding->20, 
     PlotStyle->Directive[{Red,Thickness[.01]}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3},  Background->White,
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[-2 < x < 2 && y > 1.,Red, Blue]],
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick,ImageSize->400]
```

[image]

... and using OP's example:

```
f2[x_]:= -x^3 +3 x^2 -2 x + 5  
fd2=FunctionDomain[{f2[x],-2<x<2 && f2[x]>4.8}, x,Reals]
(* -2. < x < 0.121115 || 0.790851 < x < 2. *)
NumberLinePlot[fd2, {x,-3,3}, ImageSize->500, ImagePadding->20,
     PlotStyle->Directive[{Red,Thickness[.01]}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f2[x], {x, -3, 3},  Background->White, PlotRange->{0,40},
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[-2 < x < 2 && y > 4.8,Red, Blue]],
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick,ImageSize->400]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

RegionFunction can also be used. With f[x] defined as in the answer by David Stork,

```
f[x_] := Sin[3 x^2] + x; 
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 1 < f[x] < Infinity]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You solve `f(x)=k` for `x` to get the borders of domains and then take a testpoint from each domain, eg. evaluate $f( (x_n+x_{n+1})/2)$ in order to see the type of domain. For solving have look at `NSolve`.

Comment: I don't think `NSolve` will work on a function defined in terms of `NIntegrate`.