# Extraneous reaped data with NDSolve and WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.1**

---

In exploring [What is the range of values $x$ for which $f(x)$ is higher than $k$ over a given domain?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72228/what-is-the-range-of-values-x-for-which-fx-is-higher-than-k-over-a-given/72257#72257), I came across the following strange behavior:

```
With[{a = 0, b = 2, k = 0.1, f = Sin[10 #] &},
 Last@Reap[
   NDSolve[{ifun[t] == f[t],
     in[a] == Boole[f[a] > k], x1[a] == a,
     s'[t] == 1, s[a] == a,
     WhenEvent[f[t] > k, {in[t] -> 1, x1[t] -> t}],
     WhenEvent[f[t] < k, If[in[t] == 1, Sow[{x1[t], t}]]; {in[t] -> 0}]},
    {}, {t, a, b}, DiscreteVariables -> {in, x1}]]
 ]
(*  {{{0.0100167, 0.304143}, {0.638335, 0.932461}, 6.76508*10^-8, {1.26665, 1.56078}}}  *)
```

Where does the `6.76508*10^-8` come from?  Only pairs are sown.  The output should be the same as the following:

```
Partition[x /. NSolve[Sin[10 x] == 1/10 && 0 < x < 2, x], 2]
(*  {{0.0100167, 0.304143}, {0.638335, 0.932461}, {1.26665, 1.56078}}  *)
```

(V10.0.2, Mac OSX 10.10.1)

Comment: Mma v9 output `{{{0.0100167, 0.304143}, 1.27866*10^-8, 1.27866*10^-8,   4.12524*10^-8, {0.638335, 0.932461}, {1.26665, 1.56078},  9.32835*10^-8}}`

Comment: If you use a `Sow[expr, tag]` the extra reaps aren't shown,so there are probably spurious `Sow`s  in the `NDSolve[]` code

Comment: Note that if you use `If[in[t] == 1, {x1[t], t}]` (without the `Sow`) and leave in the `Reap` you also reap something. As @belisarius mentions this is a spurious Sow with out a tag in NDSolve. Kernel code can not use Sow without a tag for exactly this reason. I'll file a bug and someone has to dig through it....

Comment: @user21 Thanks.  I did report it last night ([CASE:2325293]).

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: FYI, I do not see this extra value in 10.0.2 or in the new 10.1 (all on windows) ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/R6jPv.png)  this looks like OSX only issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, this bug has been fixed as of version 10.1.

```
With[{a = 0, b = 2, k = 0.1, f = Sin[10 #] &}, 
  Last@Reap[NDSolve[{ifun[t] == f[t], in[a] == Boole[f[a] > k], x1[a] == a,   
      s'[t] == 1, s[a] == a, WhenEvent[f[t] > k, {in[t] -> 1, x1[t] -> t}], 
      WhenEvent[f[t] < k, If[in[t] == 1, Sow[{x1[t], t}]]; {in[t] -> 0}]}, {}, {t, a, b}, 
      DiscreteVariables -> {in, x1}]]]

(* {{{0.0100167, 0.304143}, {0.638335, 0.932461}, {1.26665, 1.56078}}} *)

{Partition[x /. NSolve[Sin[10 x] == 1/10 && 0 < x < 2, x], 2]}

(* {{{0.0100167, 0.304143}, {0.638335, 0.932461}, {1.26665, 1.56078}}} *)
```